# Entity Framework Core 7 keeps creating the same migration for Nullable DateTime field

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have entities, where nullable UpdatedDate fields exist.

```
var defaultPolicy = new MatchingPolicy()
{
    Id = Guid.Parse("5cf3f8e5-50e1-47c8-aa42-40b1824ea099"),
    CompanyId = null,
    Name = "Name",
    Status = MatchingPolicyStatus.Draft,
    Type = MatchingPolicyType.Default,
    Description = "Blabla.",
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 11, 11, 35, 8, 586, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(1258),
};

var defaultPolicyVersion = new MatchingPolicyVersion()
{
    Id = Guid.Parse("5cf3f8e5-50e1-47c8-aa42-40b1824ea098"),
    CreatedByUserName = "System",
    MatchingPolicyId = defaultPolicy.Id,
    ReviewerUserName = "System",
    Status = MatchingPolicyApprovalStatus.Approved,
    Version = 1,
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 11, 11, 35, 8, 586, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    UpdatedDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 11, 11, 35, 8, 586, DateTimeKind.Utc),
};

var defaultGroups = new[]
{
     new MatchingPolicyGroup
     {
         Id = Guid.Parse("1e93b3f9-4ed8-4b90-a859-31b6503ec89f"),
         MatchingPolicyVersionId = defaultPolicyVersion.Id,
         Group = MatchingPolicyGroupType.Full,
         CreatedDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 11, 11, 35, 8, 586, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(1258),
     },
     new MatchingPolicyGroup
     {
         Id = Guid.Parse("b08f004f-a62d-409e-8025-337f0eb73054"),
         MatchingPolicyVersionId = defaultPolicyVersion.Id,
         Group = MatchingPolicyGroupType.Possible,
         CreatedDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 11, 11, 35, 8, 586, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(1258),
     },
};
```

And I'm trying to add them to db by using HasData

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MatchingPolicy>().HasData(defaultPolicy);
modelBuilder.Entity<MatchingPolicyVersion>().HasData(defaultPolicyVersion);
entity.HasData(defaultGroups);
modelBuilder.Entity<Scheme>().Property(u => u.MatchingPolicyId).HasDefaultValue(defaultPolicy.Id);
```

But It always creates the same migration with updating UpdatedDate even if this migration already exists. How can I fix that?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace DashboardISP.DAL.PostgreSQL.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class TestMigr : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_policies",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("5cf3f8e5-50e1-47c8-aa42-40b1824ea099"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_policy_groups",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("1e93b3f9-4ed8-4b90-a859-31b6503ec89f"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_policy_groups",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("b08f004f-a62d-409e-8025-337f0eb73054"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_policy_versions",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("5cf3f8e5-50e1-47c8-aa42-40b1824ea098"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: new DateTime(2022, 8, 11, 11, 35, 8, 586, DateTimeKind.Utc));

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("0da103bd-4753-4e01-bc3b-9dd1316861f9"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("2f95ee66-ce3d-4c37-9c76-d89cb5a6114c"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("3b0768e4-c774-4228-8aad-150f9a6aed1b"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("4542bf1e-219f-4e2e-83a1-5064c627c919"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("6811980f-9890-452f-a358-82678cfb34b4"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("6f77d0d9-0c2d-477c-9f0f-87b1e69bbda1"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("868feacb-f89f-4605-887b-ba068a1f05bc"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("93c1fbb6-6a86-4fdf-b298-3a32998045c4"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("9d00f543-07c8-4938-8d2e-7157720c7840"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("b3434fcc-aa01-4630-a620-7219515fb3b7"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("b97737f0-0237-4d95-b8cb-86c706cd9e33"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("ff64a9ed-314a-49ff-821a-085c491bd7c1"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_policies",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("5cf3f8e5-50e1-47c8-aa42-40b1824ea099"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_policy_groups",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("1e93b3f9-4ed8-4b90-a859-31b6503ec89f"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_policy_groups",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("b08f004f-a62d-409e-8025-337f0eb73054"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_policy_versions",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("5cf3f8e5-50e1-47c8-aa42-40b1824ea098"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: new DateTime(2022, 8, 11, 11, 35, 8, 586, DateTimeKind.Utc));

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("0da103bd-4753-4e01-bc3b-9dd1316861f9"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("2f95ee66-ce3d-4c37-9c76-d89cb5a6114c"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("3b0768e4-c774-4228-8aad-150f9a6aed1b"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("4542bf1e-219f-4e2e-83a1-5064c627c919"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("6811980f-9890-452f-a358-82678cfb34b4"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("6f77d0d9-0c2d-477c-9f0f-87b1e69bbda1"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("868feacb-f89f-4605-887b-ba068a1f05bc"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("93c1fbb6-6a86-4fdf-b298-3a32998045c4"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("9d00f543-07c8-4938-8d2e-7157720c7840"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("b3434fcc-aa01-4630-a620-7219515fb3b7"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("b97737f0-0237-4d95-b8cb-86c706cd9e33"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "matching_rule_templates",
                keyColumn: "id",
                keyValue: new Guid("ff64a9ed-314a-49ff-821a-085c491bd7c1"),
                column: "updated_date",
                value: null);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set it directly as nullable on the model builder, add NonGeneratedValue, and also tried to set UpdatedDate fields manually by adding specified Datetime to it, or null but I always have the same issue with re-creation same migration.

Comment: Is the `ContextModelSnapshot` updated?

Comment: @ManuelFabbri yes. snapshot updated. All I need it to seed this data.